# Merge function two vectors into a third

Tags: c++, vector, merge

I'm trying to merge or combine 2 vectors like

`vector a{1,2}`
and
`vector b{3,4}`
into a third
`vector c{1,3,2,4}`.

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
vector<int> append(vector<int> a, vector<int> b)
{
int n = a.size();
int m = b.size();
vector<int> c(n+m);
int i;
for(i=0; i<n;i++)
    c[i]=a[i];
for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    c[n+i]=b[i];

return c;
}
vector<int> merge(vector<int>a,vector<int>b)
{

vector<int>c(a.size()+b.size());
int x=0;
for(int i=0;i<a.size();i=+2){
    c.push_back(a[x]);
    c.push_back(b[x]);
    x++;
}
return c;
}
main()
{
int input,input2;
vector<int> one;
cout<<"Give inputs for vetor #1. When done give -1 as input"<<endl;
while((cin>>input)&& input!=-1)
    one.push_back(input);

vector<int> two;
cout<<"Give inputs for vector #2. When done give -1 as input"<<endl;
while((cin>>input2)&& input2!=-1)
    two.push_back(input2);
vector<int> three;
three=merge(one,two);
for(int i=0;i<three.size();i++)
    cout<<three[i]<<endl;

}
```

I have this code, but the output is wrong it outputs

`0 0 0 0 1 3`

When it should output

`1 3 2 4`

Can I get some help on what I'm doing wrong with the merge function?
I've tried searching, but wasn't able to find an example that was able to help me.
I saw a few other examples but I could not get it to work.
I think that vector `c` size is wrong since it outputs 6 values instead of 4. But I have no idea how that is happening.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should pass those vectors in by reference. Otherwise it is making copies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `push_back` member functions adds a new element onto the end of a vector.  Since you already sized the vector with 4 elements in your example, the `push_back` calls will increase its length even more:

```
vector<int>c(a.size()+b.size());
```

The result is that those original four places are left untouched (in their zero state), as the new values are tacked on to the end of the vector.  Change your declaration of `c` to the following, which will initialize an empty vector to start with:

```
vector<int>c;
```

That's probably the bug you are hunting.